# Устаревшие обращения

Tags: этимология, этикет

Какие существовали устаревшие обращения и как их правильно употреблять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

До революции существовало несколько общих обращений. Обращением, добавляемым к имени, было "господин", "госпожа". Безличным обращением было "сударь", "сударыня". К титулованным особам существовало следующие обращения:
к царю и царице - "ваше императорское величество"; к принцам и великим князьям (княгиням) - "ваше императорское высочество"; к князьям царской крови - "ваше высочество"; к кньязьям, потомкам царей и жалованным светлейшим князьям - "ваша светлость"; к князьям, графам, герцогам и баронам - "ваше сиятельство"; к остальным дворянам - "ваше благородие".

Comment: Добавление: милостивый государь и милостивая государыня.